# (1.8.9) Custom Texture Pack creation: Texture pack being recognised but textures not showing up

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-resource-packs

I decided to create my own texture pack for version 1.8.9. I setup the file structure and changed the bed texture a bit. It should change the red bed sheet to a mint to aqua gradient, but for some reason it doesn't appear?

Here's the file structure with the size of the pngs between brackets:

```
assets
L minecraft
  L textures
    L bed_feet_end.png (16x16)
    L bed_feet_side.png (16x16)
    L bed_feet_top.png (16x16)
    L bed_head_end.png (16x16)
    L bed_head_side.png (16x16)
    L bed_head_top.png (16x16)
pack.mcmeta
pack.png (500x500)
```

Here's a screenshot:
[image: Screenshot of the file structure]

Here are the contents of the `pack.mcmeta` file:

```
{
  "pack": {
    "pack_format": 1,
    "description": "Hukyfi's Minty Aqua Texture Pack (v1)"
  }
}
```

This is all compressed into `Hukyfi's Minty Aqua Texture Pack (v1).zip`

The game recognises the pack but doesn't load the `pack.png` thumbnail.

[image: The texture pack being selected]

And when I get into the game, the bed texture hasn't changed:

[image: bed not appearing with the changed texture]

I tried unzipping other texture packs to disect and check if they had done anything differently but it doesn't seem like it.

What am I missing? Did I do something incorrectly?

Answer (score 1):

The textures have to be in the right directory.  Create a folder named 'blocks' in the textures folder and then put the textures in there.  They have to match up with the model in the following directory.  assets>minecraft>models>block then after that find the model for the bed block.  I suggest looking at the default textures for the minecraft version you are on.  You can find it by going in the resource pack folder from minecraft, go back a folder, then go into the versions folder and select the version you are on.  After that open up the jar file with a archiver like winrar.  In the jar open the assets folder and that is the textures.  I have a windows computer and don't have a mac.  Since you are on mac it is a little difficult to explain, because I can't give you a directory.  I hope that helps you now and in the future.

Comment: Yeah, just to sum up what he said in the simplest way possible in your textures folder create a folder called `blocks` and put the bed textures in there.